# For Some Reason V is Unbound

Tags: scheme

I'm going through a list of tutorials (http://www.shido.info/lisp/scheme4_e.html). I have got to exercise 2.4 and this is my attempt at an answer. I've already seen the answer so I know it the wrong answer. But I want to get my solution "working". I had to use syntax that is used in later exercises to simplify the problem or my answer. For some reason when I try execute the main function (ballthrown) with some reasonable arguments the interpreter just come back and says that v is unbound and asks for a value for it. I'm using mit schemer.

```
(define pi (* 4 (atan 1.0)))
(define g 9.8)

; calculate the distance that a ball goes when thrown with an initial velocity

(define (d2r d)
    (* (/ d pi 180)))

(define (fftime v)
    (* (/ v 2 g)))

(define (dur v t)
    (* v t))

(define (hozvec v1 r)
    (* v1 (cos r)))

(define (vervec v1 r)
    (* v1 (sin r)))

(define (ballthrown v1 d1)
  (let ((h (hozvec v1 (d2r d1))) (v (vervec v1 (d2r d1)))
    (let ((t (fftime v)))))
       (dur h t)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is `ballthrown` properly indented according to the parentheses.

```
(define (ballthrown v1 d1)
  (let ((h (hozvec v1 (d2r d1)))
        (v (vervec v1 (d2r d1)))
        (let ((t (fftime v)))))
    (dur h t))) ; v and let is never used
```

Now I just entered this in DrRacket and pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and it moved the `let` right under `v` telling me that `let` is one of the bindings you are making in the outer `let`. Do you see that `v` cannot exist at the time `v` is evaluated the way it is?

You are probably missing a closing parentheses in the outer `let` and you have one too many in the inner `let`. These two cancel each other out. THe correct version would be:

```
(define (ballthrown v1 d1)
  (let ((h (hozvec v1 (d2r d1)))
        (v (vervec v1 (d2r d1))))
    (let ((t (fftime v)))     
      (dur h t))))
```

I strongly urge you to get an editor that matches parentheses or better, one that indents the code accordingly so that you can easily see the when you are doing mistakes.

Comment: I  tried this in DrRacket and it did not work. It kept saying expression body was missing.

Comment: Eg `(let ())` has no body while `(let () 1)` does.

Comment: It worked. When I tried it I didn't put the brackets in the right place. Thanks dude.